# How to login with curl and get link download in other website

Tags: php, curl

I have a website i want get link download from it , but this website request me login , and i create login with curl , but it not work !
this is my code
config.php

```html
$config['id']   = 'dinhvanvu94@gmail.com'; // 
$config['password'] =  'nhocmiss@2'; //
```

curl.php

```html
class cURL {
var $headers;
var $user_agent;
var $compression;
var $cookie_file;
var $proxy;
 function __construct($cookies=TRUE,$cookie='cook.txt',$compression='gzip',$proxy='') {
  $this->headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';
  $this->headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
  $this->headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
  $this->user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36';
  $this->compression=$compression;
  $this->proxy=$proxy;
  $this->cookies=$cookies;
  if ($this->cookies == TRUE) $this->cookie($cookie);
 }
 function cookie($cookie_file) {
  if (file_exists($cookie_file)) {
  $this->cookie_file=$cookie_file;
  } else {
  fopen($cookie_file,'w') or $this->error('The cookie file could not be opened. Make sure this directory has the correct permissions');
  $this->cookie_file=$cookie_file;
  fclose($this->cookie_file);
  }
 }
 
 function getheader($url) {
  $process = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
  curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent);
  if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
  if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);
  curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression);
  curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  //curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_CAINFO, NULL);
  curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_CAPATH, NULL);
  $return = curl_exec($process);
  curl_close($process);
  return $return;
 }
```

download.php

```html
include('start.php');

function _login()
{
 global $html, $curl, $config;
 
 preg_match('#<input type="hidden" value="(.*?)" name="fs_csrf" />#',$html,$fs_csrf);
 
 $data = 'fs_csrf=' . $fs_csrf[1] . '&LoginForm%5Bemail%5D=' . urlencode($config['id']). '&LoginForm%5Bpassword%5D=' . urlencode($config['password']) . '&LoginForm%5BrememberMe%5D=0&LoginForm%5BrememberMe%5D=1&yt0=%C4%90%C4%83ng+nh%E1%BA%ADp';
 $curl->post('https://www.fshare.vn/login',$data);
}

$html = $curl->get('https://www.fshare.vn/file/TM5MQ3VX2T');
if(!preg_match('#<a style="cursor: pointer;color: \#999999;" title="(.*?)"#', $html, $acc))
{
 // chua dang nhap
 _login();
 
}

$link = $curl->get('https://www.fshare.vn/download/index');

echo $link;
```

and start.php

```html
include('config.php');
include('curl.php');
$curl = new cURL();
```

This í my code and it word to login thi web but it not get link

Comment: Hope they are not legitimate details

Answer (score 0):

Your email and password are not stored in the config array, they are in a comment.

```
$config['id']       = 'THIS IS WHERE YOU WRITE YOUR EMAIL'; 
$config['password'] =  'THIS IS WHERE YOU WRITE YOUR PASSWORD';
```

You are trying to use `$curl->get()` and `$curl->post()` in your download.php file. These methods are not defined.Is the class code written by you?